# ElasticSearch search query for has many relationship models rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch server for search book with all types of book's ISBN, book title and book's subjects title. I have done indexing using of three models which has relationship like,

Book hash_many additional_isbns, subjects

Book hash_one aliase

And my indexing looks like,

```
{
"_index":"books","_type":"book","_id":"9781135028411","_score":0.6377245,
    "_source":{"book_vbid": "9781135028411","book_title": "Objectivity, Science and Society","book_author":"Paul A Komesaroff",
               "additional_isbn": [{"isbn_value": "0415474876"},{"isbn_value": "9780415474870"}],
               "aliase": {"eisbn_canonical":"9781135028411","isbn_canonical":"9781135028411","print_isbn_canonical":"9780415474870","isbn13":"9781135028411","isbn10":"1135028419"},
               "subjects": [{"title": "General"},{"title": "General"},{"title": "General"},{"title": "Physical &amp; Earth Sciences -&gt; Science -&gt; General"},{"title": "Social Sciences -&gt; Philosophy -&gt; General"},{"title": "Social Sciences -&gt; Social Sciences -&gt; General"}]}},{
"_index":"books","_type":"book","_id":"9781135027896","_score":0.6348529,
    "_source":{"book_vbid": "9781135027896","book_title": "Beyond Empiricism","book_author":"Andrew Tudor",
                "additional_isbn": [{"isbn_value": "0415475007"},{"isbn_value": "9780415475006"}],
                "aliase": {"eisbn_canonical":"9781135027896","isbn_canonical":"9781135027896","print_isbn_canonical":"9780415475006","isbn13":"9781135027896","isbn10":"1135027897"},
                "subjects": [{"title": "General"},{"title": "General"},{"title": "General"},{"title": "Physical &amp; Earth Sciences -&gt; Science -&gt; General"},{"title": "Social Sciences -&gt; Philosophy -&gt; General"},{"title": "Social Sciences -&gt; Social Sciences -&gt; General"}]}},{
"_index":"books","_type":"book","_id":"9781134429059","_score":0.6258716,
    "_source":{"book_vbid": "9781134429059","book_title": "Your Murderer","book_author":"Vassily Aksyonov",
                "additional_isbn": [{"isbn_value": "9057551039"},{"isbn_value": "9789057551031"}],
                "aliase": {"eisbn_canonical":"9781134429059","isbn_canonical":"9781134429059","print_isbn_canonical":"9789057551031","isbn13":"9781134429059","isbn10":"1134429053"},
                "subjects": [{"title": "General"},{"title": "General"},{"title": "Humanities -&gt; Performing Arts -&gt; General"},{"title": "Humanities -&gt; TheatrGeneral"}]}}
```

I have search method like,

```
def self.search(query, options = {})
es_options =
  {
    query: {
      query_string: {
        query:            query,
        default_operator: 'AND',
    }
  },
  sort:  '_score',
}.merge!(options)
__elasticsearch__.search(es_options) end
```

My requirement is like when i do search on `Book.search('general')`, searching must be on subjects's values of all books only. 
How i can do searching only on subjects but not on other columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I search for an object in two specific columns with just to give you a good picture of how you can add queries.  The second query is  how you would do your exact query in elastic search:

```
User.search( from: 0, size: 1000, query: { bool: { must: [ {match: { assembly_district: "AD\-13"}}, {match: { election_district: "ED\-011"}} ] } } ).records.last
```

This will return the first 1000 records that match AssemblyDistrict AD-13 and 'ALSO' election_district ED-011.  So in your case you would do:

```
Book.search( query: { bool: { must: [ {match: { subject: "general"}} ] } } ).results
```

'From' is the offset, 'size' is the max data-set returned.  Also, a key thing I see a lot of people overlook is that when you are searching through data where you know the exact values you're looking for in your database you can use Filters instead of Queries and they will be much faster.  The below would be how to use filters if you knew you needed an exact match to the subject "general" and not something roundabout or close to it.

```
Book.search( query: { bool: { filter: [ {term: { subject: "general"}} ] } } ).results
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So i have requirement like i want to search only on title of all subjects of all books and need that result only.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm typing from my phone right now but I would recommend trying to change the query in the middle to subject: { title: 'general' } instead of subject: "general".  I'll take a deeper look when I get back to my comp.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use `query_string` query either you can change `default field` which is `_all` as default https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_default_field:

```
{
    query: {
        query_string: {
            query:            query,
            default_operator: 'AND',
            default_field : 'subject.title'
        }
    }
}
```

or you can use `fields` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field:

```
{
    query: {
        query_string: {
            query:            query,
            default_operator: 'AND',
            fields : ['subject.title']
        }
    }
}
```

I guess it would be better if you take field name as a parameter in your  method.

Comment: I need to search for only title of subjects. So can i make query like subjects[:title] means it will search for 'title' field of subjects only

Comment: You can make ["subject.title"]